# Django - models

Tags: python, django, django-model

Как передать first_field из первой модели во вторую

```py
class One(models.Model):
    first_field = models.ForeignKey(User)
    second_field
    third_field
    ...
    
class Two(models.Model):
    first_field = models.ForeignKey(User)
    second_field = first_field_from_One
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы подразумеваете: как связать эти два класса (модели).

Ответ будет расплывчатым, поскольку не ясна ваша логика.

Воспользоваться такой же связью один ко многим, как вы используете для `User`

```py
class One(models.Model):
  first_field = models.ForeignKey(User)
  second_field
  third_field
...

class Two(models.Model):
  first_field = models.ForeignKey(User)
  second_field = models.ForeignKey(One, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

в данном случае во втором поле второй модели будет досутпна вся сущность `One` модели и к ней можно обратиться

```py
first_from_one = Two.objects.get(pk=1).second_field.first_field
```

Или написать свой `create` метод для класса `Two`

```py
def create_two(self, first_field, second_field):
    two = self.create(first_field, second_field)
```

И передавать нужные вам параметры при созданиии

```py
f = One.objects.get(pk=111)
two = Two()
two.create_two(User.objects.get(username="Name"), f.first_field)
```

Но это выглядит не очень в данном случае, поскольку вы используете `User` сущность для поля, которое вам необходимо

Comment: Да немного запутался и получился глупый вопрос, спасибо)

Comment: @MaksimAlekseev на здоровье

Comment: Метод create, думаю то, о чем я как раз думал